# How to identify XPages errors at the console

Tags: javascript, binding, xpages

I have an XPages application that has been running in production for a few years now and has been built on continually to add new functionality. In the last few months I have noticed errors like these below on the server console. The console advises to check the error-log-0.xml file, but what is reported there doesn't really lead me to any useful conclusions as to what is causing the problem.

```
2014-11-27T07:27:12.156+00:00 SEVERE CLFAD0131E: Unable to push data because: Unable to open database: com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding@539c539c
2014-11-27T07:27:12.156+00:00 SEVERE CLFAD0134E: Exception processing XPage request 
2014-11-27T07:27:12.359+00:00 SEVERE CLFAD0131E: Unable to push data because: Error while executing JavaScript computed expression
2014-11-27T07:27:12.359+00:00 SEVERE com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing JavaScript computed expression com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase 
2014-11-27T07:27:12.375+00:00 SEVERE CLFAD0134E: Exception processing XPage request 
2014-11-27T07:27:16.468+00:00 SEVERE CLFAD0131E: Unable to push data because: Unable to open database: com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding@539c539c 
2014-11-27T07:27:16.468+00:00 SEVERE Unable to open database: com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding@539c539c com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase 
2014-11-27T07:27:16.468+00:00 SEVERE CLFAD0134E: Exception processing XPage request
```

The application in question has a number of additional databases linked to it, for instance we're using a flash upload control for multiple file uploads and they are stored in a separate db. Therefore the filedownload control is actually listing the attachments in number of documents in a different database to the main document. Similarly, there is another database for storing multiple "reference" documents associated with the main document, so on another page I have a repeat control listing the values on these reference documents in a nice table, but the data is coming from a different db.

The first thing I did was make sure that the ACL is the same on all the databases that are linked to the main app, thereby ruling out an access issue. The application itself is on a server that uses Active Directory to authenticate users (via the Kerberos value on person docs in the NAB) rather than their username and password.

So my question is, how do I identify what is causing these errors? The valuebiniding is failing somewhere but I don't how to translate JavaScriptValueBinding@539c539c in to an actual control on a page. The application itself is very complex these days with a lot of code in it and links to the databases all over the code. I can't reproduce this problem and I don't know what effect this has on a user's session when the server logs it, but identifying the control that triggers the error will at least allow me to add better error handling. We use Try Catch everywhere in the system so I am surprised this happens at all.

Any ideas how to identify the offending code block ?

Comment: Does the XPages log file mention anything useful? You can use XPages Log File Reader from OpenNTF for easy access to the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a custom error page, XPages OpenLog Logger on OpenNTF will catch all uncaught exceptions and log out the component and details of where the error is occurring. It's significantly speeded up my development and was one of the key pieces of functionality I wanted to be able to offer in the project. Note in the screenshot below of the error passed to Open Log all the SSJS code is displayed, but it has no try/catch block.

[image]

The link to XPages OpenLog Logger is http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XPages%20OpenLog%20Logger

Comment: Cheers for the suggestion. I had no idea that open logger would do that. Is it a big job to fit it in an application or is it something that just sits on the server watching for errors in any app on the server ? I'll have a look this afternoon, hopefully it will point me in the right direction then.

Comment: There are two versions. One's an OSGi plugin, like the Extension Library. You will need to enable the library in Xsp Properties though, because there isn't a component to drop onto the page. The other is files to go into each NSF. Personally, I'd recommend the former - it's best practice. The documentation should be clear enough, but if not, let me know.

Comment: Hi Paul, I have downloaded the OSGi and NSF code, got the example OpenLogJava.nsf file sending errors to a new openlog.nsf file on my dev server fine. I wanted to use the OSGi version so I have used Update site to add it to the server, and installed the library in designer (com.paulwithers.openLog.library.StarterLibrary). I added the bean to my app, ticked the library (like the Extension Lib) to include it in the app but I got errors on the console. It said "cannot find class .... OpenLogPhaseListener in NSF" So I added the package to the db, then got "Cannot find lib com....StarterLibrary"

Comment: any ideas why it won't work as a plugin? I have installed the package in the app now, and deselected to include the library, unlike the extension library which is included. I suppose this way at least the package is included and other developers don't have to install the plugin on their machine to work with this app. But I followed the guides you put together, and the OSGi plugin was installed on the server with Update Site - is there a way to check at the console if it's actually installed properly?

Comment: Yes, if you issue the console command "tell http osgi diag com.paulwithers.openLog". It looks like the console command check is case sensitive

Comment: I'm getting "cannot find bundle com.paulwithers.openLog"  I've re-added it via the Update Site db, and restarted HTTP. It's not a big issue but my curious nature means I won't rest until it's resolved!

Comment: It's worth checking the notes.ini variable points to the Update Site db. Also remember you need "restart task http" (or "res task http") to fully reload the JVM. "tell http restart" doesn't do it

Comment: It was the notes.ini setting - I only created the Update Site db yesterday and didn't realise that the ini needed updating. All working now, many thanks!

Comment: I've been through the entire system and added the openlogBean.addError code all over my try catch blocks. It has already helped identify a number of null pointers in the code that I have fixed but I am no closer to resolving the original error. I see in the logs the message :  Unable to open database: com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding@6eed6eed but it's not telling me which component is causing it. Plus, if I force a connection to an invalid db, the log prints the name of the db it's unable to open....

Comment: The error I get is as if it's trying to open "com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding@6eed6eed"

Comment: Do you have any components on the page without an ID? It's a JavaScriptValueBinding, so it's SSJS that's assigned to a property and trying to open a database. The other thing to check is the phase it's occurring in. This blog post tells you how to find which phase it's occurring in http://www.intec.co.uk/optimising-view-data-and-avoiding-errors/. It may be related to when the code is running.

Comment: I can't find any with missing ID's but I will keep looking. The weird thing is that it seems to only happen to a few users. I've ruled out access to the db's that it links to being the issue. The users are on a range of browsers as well (IE/Chrome/Notes with IE). I've managed to find in the Domino Web Server Log that this issue is happening after a partial refresh on a computed field. The field is computed to be the sum of the 4 number fields above it and onBlur for each of them updates the total. It's this partial refresh that triggers the error page where we see the errors described.

Comment: Check the phase. I've seen errors be thrown during the ApplyRequestValues phase with computed content in the detail facet of a DataView. It doesn't cause a problem, because it's display content, so also gets recalculated successfully during later phases of the partial refresh. I don't know the exact cause to identify if the same could happen with a repeat control - I've not encountered an error in ApplyRequestValues for a repeat control.

Comment: Well it looks like I've managed to fix the issue - page persistence settings are now Keep on Disk - previously it was keep current page in memory. As soon as I changed that all the valuebinding errors stopped. I haven't seen one custom error page in 24 hours! I am still getting 1 random nullpointer error that mentions a pager on a dialog box, not sure what causes that but it's not sending people to the error page so I assume that the try/catch is handling it and the user continues unaware. Would this suggest something is wrong with the phases? Thanks for all your help though! OpenLog is brill